Nexe does not include entry file in build (MODULE_NOT_FOUND)
After building an executable, the .exe works when run from the original build path. However, when I move the build to a new folder, the application breaks. See error below.

The index.js file that it cannot find is the entry file used in the build script. The reason it works on the original build folder, I presume, is because the .exe can find it in its original location when the build command was run.
Here is the build script.
const { compile } = require('nexe')
const { version } = require('./package.json')

const inputAppName = '../index.js'
const outputAppName = `../build/InfinityDataBank_v${version}`

compile({
    input: inputAppName,
    output: outputAppName,
    build: true,
    clean: false,
    verbose: false
}).then((err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('success')
})

The reason for the .. is because I run the compile script from within the build folder to be able to have the script work in this location. I have tried the same from the project root with no positive results.
Thanks in advance

I found this issue in the nexe repository that led me to the root cause of the issue.
https://github.com/nexe/nexe/issues/1062
After installing and building using Node version 16.20.2 the resulting build was able to work as expected. It appears that newer version of Node break nexe.
An open request to the nexe contributors would be to:

Document the latest compatible version of nodejs
Consider fixing the product to be compatible with more recent versions of nodejs

